# Why "@echo off" is not making a difference?

Tags: file, command, window, batch-file

In a .bat file like this :

```
@echo off
start C:/my_test.exe
```

Why the first line is making no difference ? I thought with "@echo off", it won't open the command window, but it still flashed and then closed, it has the same effect as without the first line. How to avoid the command window to open at all ? In other words, how to write the .bat file, so that when it runs, ONLY my exe file opens, the Windows command prompt window won't show up at all.

I want the app to run at start up, so I was told to create the bat file and put it in the Start up folder, so to not having the command prompt window show up at all, I was suggested to create a short cut, how to create a short cut and save it in the start up folder, I need to do it from my app, what does the DOS command look like ? It need to first find where the start up folder is, then create and save the shortcut in the start up folder.

Comment: In order to create a shortcut in your startup folder you can right click your exe, drag it to the start button and hold for a second. Then, the start menu will pop up and you should continue dragging it to the "all programs" folder, and then the startup folder. then you should drop the right mouse button and from the menu that pops up choose "create shortcuts here". You can create the shortcut directly for your exe, no need to go through a bat file. The instructions are for windows 7, but the idea is the same for other Microsoft operating systems.

Comment: I'm developing an app, I need it to auto start itself without users to go through the above steps, it's a calendar program that checks to see if there are things to be done in that day and hour, how can the app create a shortcut in the startup folder when user runs it for the first time ?

Comment: For win 7, see this: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1401-startup-programs-change.html . On XP you can create the shortcut in the "AllUsers" startup folder (i.e. "%AllUsersProfile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few of possible options:

1. Make installer for your application (most of them automate [startup]shortcut creation).
2. You can register your application in the registry for startup, here is sample command-line example:

   `reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Test /t REG_SZ /d test.exe`
3. You can create shortcut with help of jscript or vbscript ([examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fywyxt64)).

***Updated***: if you don't want to go installer or jni/jna solutions, here are q&d examples for [2]:

```
String command = "reg add \"HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\" /v Test /t REG_SZ /d test.exe /f";

try {
    int result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor();
    System.out.println("command execution " + ((result == 0) ? "succeded" : "failed"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle error
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and [3]:

```
// construct your script body
String script = "Set Shell = CreateObject(\"WScript.Shell\")\r\n"
              + "Folder = Shell.SpecialFolders(\"Startup\")\r\n"
              + "Set link = Shell.CreateShortcut(Folder + \"\\\\test.lnk\")\r\n"
              + "link.Arguments = \"arg1 arg2\"\r\n"
              + "link.Description = \"Test shortcut\"\r\n"
              + "link.TargetPath = \"c:\\\\bin\\\\test.exe\"\r\n"
              + "link.WorkingDirectory = \"c:\\\\bin\"\r\n"
              + "link.Save\r\n";

File vbs = new File("test.vbs");
FileWriter writer = null;

try {
    // write script contents to file
    writer = new FileWriter(vbs);
    writer.write(script);
    writer.close();
    writer = null;
    // execute
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript.exe \"" + vbs.getAbsolutePath() + "\"").waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle error
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (writer != null) { try { writer.close(); } catch (Exception e) {} }
```

Comment: How to do it with Java, I know Java can execute Windows commands, such as "start C:/test.exe", I wonder if the command can be simplified into one line, or be saved into an executable file, I just need to run that file.

Comment: Excellent ! These are the closest answers to my question, one thing I'm still unclear is : I want my app to work on all versions of Windows, at least XP,Vista and 7, how do I do that through your solutions. What's the difference between the 2 methods, which one is more reliable over different versions of Windows ? And if I have the code in my app, would it cause a problem if it executes every time the app runs, causing multiple copies of entry. I guess this is the last hurdle !

Answer (score 4):

@echo off just tell the shell interpeter not to print the executed commands on the command prompt. It does not mean the command prompt itself will not be executed, as the command propt (i.e. cmd.exe) is the environment where batch file run. In order to get the effect that you are after just create a shortcut to your exe.

Comment: Add goto the properties of the shorcut and run it mnimized instead of normal wndow ! Doing this will ensure the console window doesnt pop up. It still however does appear on the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

The console window is opened *before* your batch file starts running. Therefore, there's nothing you can put inside the batch file to prevent the console window from appearing.

However, you can control *how* the console window is launched. If this is from a shortcut on your desktop, there should be a setting in the shortcut that tells the window to open minimised, for example.

If your batch file really is as described and only launches one executable, why not simply launch the executable directly instead of going through a one-line batch file?

Comment: See my edited question, I don't know how to create a shortcut in the startup folder from my app. User just needs to run it once, it automatically finds where the startup folder is and saves it's own shortcut into the startup folder, how ?

Answer (score 0):

hi this might be a simpler solution http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=1660 is a Bat_To_Exe_Converter.exe it will convert your batch file to an executable with an option to run silently (without seeing the CMD window) i love this little tool.